# Fitting curve in python - fitting parameters

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a curve to my data in Python, as follows:

```
def func(p1,p2,p3,x):
    return p1*((p2-x)/p2)^(-p3)
```

And I call this function in an other function, and trying to fit:

```
f1 = func(p1,p2,p3,x)
popt, pcov = curve_fit(f1, T, Susceptibility)
```

But Python doesn't regard `p1,p2,p3` as a fitting parameter, becouse I get this error message:
`global name 'p1' is not defined`

Comment: Please add the information what library this is about. In general you should also post error messages in verbatim. Please edit this information into your post.

Answer (score 1):

Read [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) more carefully, `x` is supposed to be the first parameter. Also you need to use a function as input instead of it's return value

```
def func(x, p1, p2, p3):
    return p1*((p2-x)/p2)^(-p3)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, T, Susceptibility)
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't notice this fault, but now I also get this message but with x instead of p1.

Comment: @Alíz Sure that's not happening somewhere else? In the above code the only things that can be undefined are `T` and `Susceptibility`.

Comment: Unfortunately I get this error message :
global name 'x' is not defined, but I don't know why.

Comment: T and Susceptibility are defined, there is no problem with them :(

Comment: @Alíz Can't help you further as this should work imo, but you can test your own code by using a debugger. Consider trying out pycharm's debugger.